# Accessing GridView Label field from Code-Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I have a gridview, and I'm trying to get the text value of a label in the textview where the code is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="someText" SortExpression="someExpression">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="someLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("someField") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to be able to get the text value of the "someLabel" from the selectedRow as a string in my codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Label someLabel = selectedRow.FindControl("someLabel") as Label;
```

EDIT:

```
    private static Control FindControlRecursive(Control parent, string id)
    {
        if (parent.ID== id)
        {
            return parent;
        }

        return (from Control ctl in parent.Controls select FindControlRecursive(ctl, id))
            .FirstOrDefault(objCtl => objCtl != null);
    }
```

and

```
Label someLabel = FindControlRecursive(GridView.SelectedRow, "someLabel") as Label;
```

EDIT 2:

```
private void imageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Label someLabel = (sender as Control).Parent.FindControl("someLabel") as Label;
}
```

Comment: This is what I have been trying: `Label tempLabel = GridView.SelectedRow.FindControl("someLabel") as Label;`, but for some reason, that isn't working. Any idea why?

Comment: @Jordan And? tempLabel is null?

Comment: I'm getting a nullreferenceexception

Comment: I'm having an issue with `parent.Name` I'm using _System.Web.UI.Control_

Comment: @Jordan oops~ it should be `parent.ID`. I copied that snippet from my winforms project.

Comment: I'm still getting null. Would it be that the row is being selected _after_ my function is run? Which would make the selectedRow = null? I have an image button field that when clicked both selects its row, and executes the function that I'm trying to write: `<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/image.png" CommandName="select" OnClick="moveDown" ID="imageButton" />`

Comment: Is this button inside the gridview?

Comment: @Jordan See my Edit 2 :) . You should be able to access the label from the button's click event since they are in the same row. Alternatively you can [`GridView.RowCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event.

Comment: Alright...I'm not getting nulls anymore! :D Thanks for all the help!